# What is IntelliJ asking for when they say "No main class specified" in configuration settings?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

What is this asking for when it say's the "No Main Class specified" in configuration settings. When I try to run my Kotlin code, this keeps coming up. I have never coded in Kotlin before(that's why I'm doing Hello World), and my only code is the one typed at the top.(If classes are like they are in Python, I have none here in the code).

[Picture of the screen when I try to run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIeL.png)

Comment: Now It say's "Class MainKt not found in module 'kotlin-crash-course.test'

Comment: I suppose you need to move your "Main.kt" under "/src/main/kotlin"

Comment: Yeah that was the issue, now it's been working.